# Custom Arabic Font working on Cordova Android 4.4 but not in 4.3

Tags: android, cordova, fonts, font-face, cordova-cli

I have added the Arabic webfont using css and its working fine on Cordova Android 4.4 versions but not working on 4.3 versions.

Is there any solution to overcome with font implementation?